# Setting up a y axis lim

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to set up a `ylim` using an if statement with data that I have read in from a csv file. Right now I have setup the if statement as the following.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data')

# Indicated your x values and y values.
x = df["x data"]
y1 = df["2nd y axis data"]
z = df["1st y axis data"]
y_pos = np.arange(len(x))

lns1 = plt.bar(y_pos,z)
plt.ylabel('Data')
plt.xlabel('Date')

plt.twinx()
lns2 = plt.plot(y_pos,y1,color='orange',linewidth=2.5)
lns3 = plt.axhline(y=10,color='red',linewidth=2.5)

if y1 < 10:
    plt.ylim([0.0,14.0])
else:
    plt.ylim(0,ymax)
```

This code as is gets me an error message. "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous."

Comment: In the code you show `ymax` is undefined. If you want further help on this, you may define it, otherwise we may close this question, since questions seeking debugging help need a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Your `ymax` is a pandas Series but needs to be a number. Check your code and the value of `ymax`.

This reproduces your error message:

```
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
plt.ylim(0, ser)

...

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. 
Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Help of `plt.ylim()`:

> Get or set the *y*-limits of the current axes.
>
> ::
>
> ymin, ymax = ylim()   # return the current ylim   ylim( (ymin, ymax)
>   )  # set the ylim to ymin, ymax   ylim( ymin, ymax )    # set the ylim
>   to ymin, ymax
>
> If you do not specify args, you can pass the *ymin* and *ymax* as
>   kwargs, e.g.::
>
> ylim(ymax=3) # adjust the max leaving min unchanged   ylim(ymin=1) #
>   adjust the min leaving max unchanged
>
> Setting limits turns autoscaling off for the y-axis.

Comment: Why does it have to be a number? I would like for it to pull the number out of the data I've read in so that it picks the largest data point to go to.

Comment: `plt.ylim()` is matplotlib function that expects two numbers, on for start and one for end of the y axis..